# Regex for password validation returning false for correct passwords

Tags: c#, regex

I have attempted to write a regular expression to validate passwords, but it returns false for valid passwords.

Passwords must have at least 3 of the following:

- Digits
- Upper case letters
- Lower case letters
- Special characters

There is no limit on password length.

This is my attempt:

```
@"^(?=(.*\d){3})(?=(.*[a-z]){3})(?=(.*[A-Z]){3})(?=(.*[^a-zA-Z\d]){3})$"
```

Also, I am completely aware of how to do this without using regular expressions. However, this is for a university task, and we have been told that we must use them.

Comment: So the password "Ab1" is valid? Or does "at least 3" mean at least 3 elements from each group?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. It must contain three or more of each.

Comment: So password Th1sIsSt@çkOv3rF!0w should validate ?

Comment: If the ç character matches [^a-zA-Z\d], then yes. It must have three or more instances of the attributes I have mentioned above. So, there should be a minimum of 12 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your only problem is that you don't **match** any characters.

```
@"^(?=(.*\d){3})(?=(.*[a-z]){3})(?=(.*[A-Z]){3})(?=(.*[^a-zA-Z\d]){3})$"
```

consists only of your lookaheads, that ensures your conditions. That means basically you require conditions with the lookaheads and on the other hand the real pattern is only `^$` matching the empty string. This regex will never return true.

Just add `.*` at the end to actually match characters. Your requirements are covered by the lookaheads.

```
@"^(?=(.*\d){3})(?=(.*[a-z]){3})(?=(.*[A-Z]){3})(?=(.*[^a-zA-Z\d]){3}).*$"
```

Comment: Only works in some cases. `gh6y78GH#^%` will validate with this despite having only two uppercase letters, as will `skfhsifcns,edche#£$444`

Comment: @StevePettifer, no will not, there is an uppercase missing.

Comment: Did you try it? Both cases I provided will be matched by your regex event though they do not meet the stated requirements.

Comment: @StevePettifer This answer is right. I tried what you said would return true, and it returns false.

Comment: @StevePettifer, See it on [Regexr](http://regexr.com/v1?38mak). Your example is not matched, just add an uppercase and it will match

Comment: Since you just need to perform the checks and don't really care about matching the whole string, you could alternatively just remove the ending `$` which was forcing a zero width string. Also @StevePettifer, it seems to me the current answer does solve the issue.

Comment: Dammit. Idiot me left 'ignore case' flag on. Apologies, it is Monday morning and I'm not quite with it yet. as an aside, I noted that Regexr doesn't seem to work in Chrome but did in FF and IE, although it claims an 'infinite' error when matching - not sure why.